# The expectation for large numbers random sequence

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose 
$$H=h_1^2+h_2^2...h_N^2$$
where $h_i$ is i.i.d Gaussian distributed random variable with zero mean and unit variance, i.e., $h_i \sim N(0,1)$. By the strong law of large numbers, we have:
$$P(\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{H}{N}=1)=1.$$

My question is: can we conclude that $\lim_{N \to \infty}E_H[\log(\frac{H}{N})]=\log(1)=0$?

Is it a direct result by the strong law of large numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: can we conclude that $\lim_{N \to \infty}E_H[\log(\frac{H}{N})]=\log(1)=0$?

One does not need the law of large numbers, CLT or any other approximation. In particular, the sum of squares of $n$ independent standard Normal variates has a Chisquared($n$) distribution with pdf, say, $f(x)$:

[image]

You seek $E[\log(\frac{X}{n})]$:

[image]

Finally, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\big\{\log(\frac{2}{n}) + \psi(\frac{n}{2})\big\} = 0$, where $\psi(z)$ denotes the digamma function `PolyGamma[0,z]`. All done.

To illustrate, here is a plot of $E[\log(\frac{X}{n})]$, as a function of $n$:

[image]

**Notes**

1. The `Expect` function used above is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.
2. `PolyGamma[0,z] = PolyGamma[z]` denotes the digamma function $\psi(z) = \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$

Comment: In your Output[2], $\log(\frac{2}{n})$ tends to be $-\infty$, so do you mean the expectation approaches to minus infinity?

Comment: My use of the term 'latter' was ambiguous. Sorry about that. It refers to the limit of the _whole_ expression. I have entered the limit formula explicitly to resolve any ambiguity.